# The web permissions API revoke() method is deprecated; what is the best way to revoke a permission such as 'geolocation'?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I am building a web interface which checks if the permission to use geolocation has already been granted using:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.state == 'prompt') {
    // Ask user for permission to use geolocation.
  }
}
```

I'd like to provide my development team with a "revokeGeolocationPermission()" function which they can use to simulate the case where a user has never given permission, to see how the system reacts. This is meant to be used during development and QA.

The MDN Web Docs page [Permissions: revoke() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke) describes exactly the functionality I need, but says:

> This feature is no longer recommended [and] may cease to work at any time

What is the recommended way to revoke permissions such as geolocation for testing and QA purposes?

Comment: It seems one has to use the browser UI to do that, it's no longer possible from code.